# How to cast away the volatile-ness?

Tags: c++, casting, volatile

How to cast away the volatile-ness? Which c++ style cast should I use?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `const_cast`.

For example,

```
volatile sample *pvs = new sample();
sample *ps = const_cast<sample*>(pvs); //casting away the volatile-ness
```

That is, `const_cast` is used to cast away both const-ness as well as volatile-ness. Unfortunately, its name doesn't contain the term "volatile". Maybe, that is because the keyword `const` is more common in use than the keyword `volatile`. As one of the comment says, `cv_cast` would have been more appropriate name!

Comment: they should call it cv_cast or something, then.

Comment: @Jason: That looks good. After all, C++ Standard often uses `cv` to mean const-volatile!

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think `const-ness` is better than `constancy`. It points to a *particular* language keyword. Also, C++ programmers use it that way. So I'm thinking of rollback. Do you agree?

Comment: @Nawaz: Hm... sure, okay, roll it back then. Both have their upsides. :)

Comment: @Nawaz: Haha no problem; it makes the post better and that's what really matters. I didn't really give my edit a second thought. :)

Comment: Is there an equivalent for `const_cast` in C ?

Comment: @Bionix1441: Use : `T * x = (T*)(obj);` syntax which you use for all kind of cast.

Comment: In C++ you shouldn't use C-like casts - i.e. (T*)obj - cause every cast type would be tried, event if you only want one special (and otherwise the compiler should terminate with an error)

Comment: @Bionix1441 there is no C cast that *only* does what `const_cast` does. The reason C++ added the `_cast`s was because C style casts did too many things with the same syntax.

Comment: @Caleth: Also, C-style cast **cannot** do what `dynamic_cast` does, so C++ added this!