# C++ cast for casting between pointers to types of the same size?

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

Say we have this signature:

```
void frobnicate(const uint8_t* raw_memory, size_t bytes);
```

Is it possible to write a C++ casting function, that will allow casting an arbitrary type (say, e.g., `uint_least8_t` or `signed char`, ...) to an `uint8_t*` to feed into that function?

All the standard offers is `reinterpret_cast` and that will of course cast from any pointer type.

By example:

```
std::vector<int>  iv = ...;
std::vector<char> cv = ...;

frobnicate(sized_ptr_cast<const uint8_t*>(iv.data()), iv.size()); // must not compile
frobnicate(sized_ptr_cast<const uint8_t*>(cv.data()), cv.size()); // should compile
```

Basically a `reinterpret_cast` with some constraints.

**Disclaimers:**

- *Please* leave aside whether `f(T*, size_t len)` is a good interface and how an iterator based interface would be better off etc.
- No `void*` please (?) :-)
- `CHAR_BIT == 8`

Comment: write a function wrap reinterpret_cast with static_assert / enable_if

Comment: @BryanChen : Just a `sizeof` check in a `static_assert` then ?

Comment: depends on how generic you want it to be. `const`, `volatile`, `alignof` comes to mind.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: `alignment` is a good point for larger types. `const`/`volatile` *should* be caught by reinterpret_cast, as that would require an additional const_cast.

Comment: @MartinBa: didn't know that. Thx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249895/how-to-cast-away-the-volatile-ness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation that wrap `reinterpret_cast` and constrain it with `static_assert`

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T sized_ptr_cast(U *p) {
    static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>::value, "");
    static_assert(sizeof(typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type) == sizeof(U), "size must be same");
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(p);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d13da2471b051d5d

Comment: Why not just take `T*` and `U*` and remove the `is_pointer` and `remove_pointer`?

Comment: @T.C. only because it op use it like `sized_ptr_cast<const uint8_t*>` instead of `sized_ptr_cast<uint8_t>`

Comment: OK, `U` can still be fixed though.

Answer (score 2):

A simple template-function doing as you asked, using [`std::pointer_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits):

```
template<class T, class P> auto sized_ptr_cast(P&& p)
-> typename std::enable_if<sizeof(std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type)
  == sizeof(std::pointer_traits<P>::element_type), T>::type
{ return reinterpret_cast<T>(p); }
```

Advantage over using `static_assert`: Uses SFINAE
Disadvantage: Bit more verbose diagnostics