# How I can retrieve the sp on an risc-v32 without having UB?

Tags: c++, riscv, riscv32

My target is the riscv32-unknown-elf (piccolo32), so it has a stack. The compiler can and will therefore use it.

Code with `volatile` looks like this:

```cpp
void* volatile sd = nullptr; // volatile to prevent optimization into register
void* volatile sp = &sd + REGISTER_SIZE; // volatile because sd is **MEHHH***
```

I don't like to use `volatile` here, since `sp` can and should be optimized into a register if possible.

**So my question is, how I can retrieve the `sp` on an risc-v32 without having UB?**

I thought that just using

```cpp
void* sd = nullptr; //may be UB
void* sp = &sd + REGISTER_SIZE;
```

is UB, since a pointer in c++ is not a pointer to a real hardware location. And that the pointer itself could be optimized away/to any other location the compiler currently likes.

Comment: What do you even think volatile is doing?  volatile only has use for memory mapped IO. It tells the compiler not to optimize away any reads or writes to that variable at a specific address. But what is your question? You only say you don't like something

Comment: Try this: [How to cast away the volatile-ness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249895/how-to-cast-away-the-volatile-ness)

Comment: `&sd` prevents the compiler from putting `sd` in a register, so just remove both of the `volatile`s.

Comment: Ah thank, you @PeteBecker, but I was sure, that this is at least implementation defined, since a pointer in c++ is not a real pointer to data. Instead its some sort of reference construct pointing to a c++ object with a lifetime connected to it. So the compiler is allowed to just compile it away.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes, when a variable must be read or be written into the memory, it can't be put into an register only. After any computation, it must be written back into memory. It's also necessary for DMA accesses, so that the value can be read or written by other hardware.
What I actually want is to override the ra with data from a dma. The ra is only in the cache, therefore this must be done on software side. And to reach the ra I need the sp. My question is therefore, how to retrieve the sp in a way which is not UB.

Comment: Write a get sp function in assembly?

Comment: What are you considering as a real pointer?  Last time I checked (yesterday), my pointers in my C++ applications were working fine.  The "smart pointers" were also working.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on a desktop.   Please provide a Use Case where there are not real pointers to data.

Comment: Many embedded platforms come with functions that can return the value of special registers.  The functions are usually supported by the compiler or by the SDK.  In essence, they are assembly language functions or inline assembly language functions.

Comment: "What I actually want is to override the ra with data from a dma" - putting aside that this is a strange thing to do, RA on RISCV is stored in a register. It may be saved to the stack when necessary, but that won't always happen and when it does it's harder to predict its location. GCC does have `__builtin_stack_address()` but I think it won't help you

Comment: Yes, the ra is stored in the ra register, but definitely saved on the stack, when the current function wants to call another address. The reason, why I want to do those strange things is, that I need to simulate an ROP attack, which then should be catched by a control flow observer.

Comment: `volatile` does not necessarily force a compiler to keep a variable in the stack.   It can inhibit some optimisations (e.g. reordering of access of that variable) but, at best, it is largely a *hint* to the compiler - compilers are permitted to ignore that hint, and [practically] often do.      If having variables "on the stack" is important to you, you would be better off reading documentation for your compiler (and maybe target system) for ways to force the compiler to do what you need.  The approaches may be compiler-specific.

Comment: @harold unfortunately, clang does not have the buildin `__builtin_stack_address()`. I wrote it in assembler, but it is not inlined by the linker with lto enabled :/. At least it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem would be to use `__builtin_stack_address()`, like @harold suggested.
But clang does not support this intrinsic. Also, some targets of gcc may not support it.

The solution for the RISC-V piccolo32 with the target option riscv32-unknown-elf is to write an own version of the intrinsic with inline assembler:

```
#if not __has_builtin(__builtin_stack_address)
// Todo(if compiler complains about "__"): wrap true buildin into another function
static void* __builtin_stack_address() {
    void* res;
    asm("mv %0,sp":"=r" (res):);
    return res;
}

#endif
```

Pure C++ or C solutions inhibit undefined behavior, since they all return an address to local storage. Or they have other issues:

The following for example

```
constexpr auto RISC_V_STACK_ALIGNMENT = 16;
constexpr void* builtin_stack_address(void* const& local = nullptr) noexcept {
    auto sp = std::bit_cast<uintptr_t>(&local);  // Relies on UB check binary output! clang and gnu may differ
    sp &= -RISC_V_STACK_ALIGNMENT;
    return std::bit_cast<void*>(sp);
}
```

does not return an address to local storage, but 2 successive calls to `builtin_stack_address` may return different values, depending on the allocated stack size and the stores made between those calls:

```
std::pair<void*,void*> test() noexcept {
    auto a = builtin_stack_address();
    volatile int i[8];
    i[0] = 1;
    i[1] = 1;
    i[2] = 1;
    i[3] = 1;
    i[4] = 1;
    fun();
    auto b = builtin_stack_address();
    return {a,b};
}
```

Creates the following asm:

```
test():                               # @test()
        addi    sp, sp, -32
        sw      ra, 28(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Spill
        sw      s0, 24(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Spill
        addi    s0, sp, 20                      #s0 = sp + 20
        andi    s0, s0, -16                     #s0 = sp + 16
        li      a0, 1
        sw      a0, 20(sp)
        sw      a0, 16(sp)
        sw      a0, 12(sp)
        sw      a0, 8(sp)
        sw      a0, 4(sp)
        call    fun
        mv      a1, sp                          # a1 = sp + 0
        andi    a1, a1, -16                     # a1 = sp + 0
        mv      a0, s0
        lw      ra, 28(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Reload
        lw      s0, 24(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Reload
        addi    sp, sp, 32
        ret
```

Where the stack pointer is evaluated as sp + 0 and sp + 16.
GCC will also evaluate complete different things due to reordering.
Therefore, it is never guaranteed to get the actual sp.